# What is the quickest way to get to the Fleet?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Once you get your starship in SWTOR to go from a planet to the Fleet (or another planet) you have to:

1. go to the spaceport,
2. up to the planet's orbital platform,
3. run to your hanger,
4. to your ship and get in,
5. hyperspace to the Fleet,
6. back out of your ship,
7. and cross the hanger to the elevator to the main level.

After all that you can finally /dance in the cantina — or whatever you need to do at the main hub of the galaxy. (Well, main hub in the SWTOR world anyway.)

Is there a faster way to get there then without having to go through all those steps every time?

Comment: Not all planets have orbital platforms, though.

Comment: Now that the looking for group (LFG) feature is in, you _could_ join a flashpoint group then immediately exit the instance after clicking the travel button that warps you to the instance. But that is a terribly mean thing to do, so never do it kids!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several ways:

- Quick travel to spaceport (cooldown 30 minutes)
- Use the emergency fleet transport (cooldown 9/12 hours for subs/F2P, reducible to none)
- Use the flashpoint transports (no cooldown)
- Travel to your stronghold, then to fleet(no cooldown)

Comment: Another option: Now with Galactic Strongholds, you can travel to your (or your guild) stronghold, then immediately Exit To Fleet.

Answer (score 10):

There is a special ability called “Emergency Fleet Pass” that you can use to instantly teleport to the fleet. It has an 9 hour long cooldown (12 for non-subscribers), although ther are 3 Legacy perks to reduce the cooldown by 3 hours each (so you can potentially have it without a cooldown).

Comment: I don't know about any other way. And I find it quite annoying too.

Comment: That's true; that's the quickest way. But it has an 18 hour cool down I believe. Is there a quick way that is more reliable?

Comment: It's in the security key shop. So you need the Security Key (physical or the app) to get that.

Comment: @Fredy31, I don't have the Secutiry Key, but I still do have the ability.

Comment: @svick Do you have the Digital Deluxe (or Collector's Edition). I think it might come with one of those, in addition to being able to be purchased through the Security Key Vendor.

Comment: @Mufasa, no, I don't. I have the normal edition. I have pre-ordered and was in the beta, but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: The pass to fleet is common to everybody. The CE thing in the vendor might be a 1-time use in addition to the normal one, not sure I haven't seen it.

Comment: Whoops, I was trying to incorporate the comments here into the answer but I see user2974's answer already has it. I rolled back so as not to make it look like you stole his info.  Sorry about that!  I'll leave the decision to add that info or not up to you, personally I think it would be useful in the top answer :)

Comment: @MatthewRead For me, the cooldown is now 12 hours (I'm a preferred player, not subscriber). Now idea what is it for F2P players, or if they even have this ability.

Comment: @svick Thanks, forgot about that.  F2P and Preferred have the same: [http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/2.3.2/942013](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/2.3.2/942013)

Answer (score 7):

If you have [registered](https://account.swtor.com/user/security-key) a [Physical Security Key](http://store.origin.com/store/ea/buy/productID.232460100) or Mobile Security Key app ([iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/star-wars-the-old-republic/id488420452?mt=8) or [Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ea.SWTORSK_na)), you can buy a Fleet Pass from the Security Key Vendor outside your capitol city or on your faction's fleet for 1,000 credits.

It has its own 1 hour cooldown, which isn't shared with the Emergency Fleet Pass.

Comment: Actually, I haven't tried it to see if it's single-use or not, I just assumed that it was.

Comment: I have tried it. It is not single use, but has an 18-hour cooldown on the usage.

Comment: @Mufasa Oh, ouch.

Comment: The Vendor Fleet Pass is a 1 hour cooldown, not 18.

Answer (score 2):

Some planets have a shuttle in their spaceport which can take you straight to it.  You will still need to take the elevator for the fleet's space hub to the main area, but this is for characters of any level which have gained access to the fleet from their class's starting area.  This is also faster than going to your own ship because you skip a loading screen and messing with the galaxy map.

Comment: Some plants have shuttles directly to the fleet elsewhere on the planet--for example, on Dromund Kaas there is a shuttle to the fleet in the southern part of the zone (around the "loop" above Grathan's estate).

Comment: Do u mean only or aswell.  On those planets?

Comment: They are in addition to the regular spaceport on that planet.

Answer (score 1):

With the Legacy system there is an unlock for Priority Transport: Fleet Vanguard Vessel which takes you to the ship hosting Operations rather than the main space station.  There's also a Personal Starship unlock which also can help getting to fleet quickly (just 2 load screens).

Answer (score -1):

NO! go to the Coruscant Taxi port, and the shuttle to fleet is to the right or left depending on which way you came in.

Comment: This was mentioned in Rodolfo's answer above. The flashpoint transports. Those are quick, and free. But they are only in limited cities; usually just one or two per planet. So if you're close, then yes, use them; but if you're not use one of the other ways.